# need help in Google Script onedit(e) to monitor restricted rows / columns or range and update in logger xls

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Below code is working and records all the changes (from entire sheet cell values) and update in logger xls.
How to restrict to monitor changes only for specific rows / columns or range

code :

```
function onEdit() {
  // This script records changes to the spreadsheet on a "Changelog" sheet.
  // The changelog includes these columns:  
  // edit the following lines to suit your needs
  // changes are only recorded from sheets listed below
  // escape regular expression metacharacters as in \. \$ \+ \* \? \( \) \[ \]
  // see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression
  // use '.+' to include all sheets
  var sheetsToWatch = ['outcome overview', 'Sheet1', 'Another sheet'];
  // name of the sheet where the changelog is stored
  var changelogSheetName = "Changelog";

  var timestamp = new Date();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();

  // if it is the changelog sheet that is being edited, do not record the change
  if (sheetName == changelogSheetName) return;

  // if the sheet name does not appear in sheetsToWatch, do not record the change
  var matchFound = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < sheetsToWatch.length; i++) {
    if (sheetName.match(sheetsToWatch[i])) matchFound = true;
  }
  if (!matchFound) return;

  var columnLabel = sheet.getRange(/* row 1 */ 1, cell.getColumn()).getValue();
  var rowLabel = sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(), /* column A */ 1).getValue();

  var changelogSheet = ss.getSheetByName(changelogSheetName);
  if (!changelogSheet) {
    // no changelog sheet found, create it as the last sheet in the spreadsheet
    changelogSheet = ss.insertSheet(changelogSheetName, ss.getNumSheets());
    // Utilities.sleep(2000); // give time for the new sheet to render before going back
    // ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
    changelogSheet.appendRow(["Timestamp", "Sheet name", "Cell address", "Column label", "Rowlabel", "Value entered"]);
    changelogSheet.setFrozenRows(1);
  }
  changelogSheet.appendRow([timestamp, sheetName, cell.getA1Notation(), columnLabel, rowLabel, cell.getValue()]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason for not using the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)? I think that could make some stuff more cleaner.

Addressing to the specific of your question, there is no built in way to actually filter the calls in the [`onEdit()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite). But you can just use an `if` statement to avoid executing changes when the range is not on your list.

So I changed your code to look like:

```
function onEdit() {
  // This script records changes to the spreadsheet on a "Changelog" sheet.
  // The changelog includes these columns:  
  // edit the following lines to suit your needs
  // changes are only recorded from sheets listed below
  // escape regular expression metacharacters as in \. \$ \+ \* \? \( \) \[ \]
  // see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression
  // use '.+' to include all sheets
  var sheetsToWatch = ['outcome overview', 'Sheet1', 'Another sheet'];

  // Range to execute the changeLog
  var minRow = 1;
  var maxRow = 3;

  var minColumn = 1;
  var maxColumn = 3;

  // name of the sheet where the changelog is stored
  var changelogSheetName = "Changelog";

  var timestamp = new Date();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();

  // if it is the changelog sheet that is being edited, do not record the change
  if (sheetName == changelogSheetName) return;

  // if the sheet name does not appear in sheetsToWatch, do not record the change
  var matchFound = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < sheetsToWatch.length; i++) {
    if (sheetName.match(sheetsToWatch[i])) matchFound = true;
  }
  if (!matchFound) return;

  if(minColumn > cell.getColumn() || cell.getColumn() > maxColumn 
     || minRow > cell.getRow() || cell.getRow() > maxRow){
    Logger.log("Change not done in the expected range, halting");
    return;
  }

  var columnLabel = sheet.getRange(/* row 1 */ 1, cell.getColumn()).getValue();
  var rowLabel = sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(), /* column A */ 1).getValue();

  var changelogSheet = ss.getSheetByName(changelogSheetName);
  if (!changelogSheet) {
    // no changelog sheet found, create it as the last sheet in the spreadsheet
    changelogSheet = ss.insertSheet(changelogSheetName, ss.getNumSheets());
    // Utilities.sleep(2000); // give time for the new sheet to render before going back
    // ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
    changelogSheet.appendRow(["Timestamp", "Sheet name", "Cell address", "Column label", "Rowlabel", "Value entered"]);
    changelogSheet.setFrozenRows(1);
  }
  changelogSheet.appendRow([timestamp, sheetName, cell.getA1Notation(), columnLabel, rowLabel, cell.getValue()]);
}
```

---

So I just modified your script adding the variables to define the range you want to be inserted in the `ChangeLog`:

```
  // Range to execute the changeLog
  var minRow = 1;
  var maxRow = 3;

  var minColumn = 1;
  var maxColumn = 3;
```

And after that you just compare with the modified cell and in case is not in the range halt the execution:

```
  if(minColumn > cell.getColumn() || cell.getColumn() > maxColumn 
     || minRow > cell.getRow() || cell.getRow() > maxRow){
    Logger.log("Change not done in the expected range, halting");
    return;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Raserhin, your input and code solved my issue :)

Comment: Actually it update the logs only when i update sheet manually, but it didn't update when cell changes occurred due to some auto function. Is there any way where it can track the changes when cells are getting updated by functions.